# Should a base class declare methods virtual if there is no need for dynamic polymorphism?

Tags: c++

Is there an advantage to using:

```
struct Base
{
    virtual void foobar();
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    virtual void foobar() override;
};
```

Instead of:

```
struct Base
{
    void foobar();
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    void foobar();
};
```

When there is no need for dynamic/run-time polymorphism? If so, why?

Thanks.

Comment: *"if there is no need for dynamic polymorphism?"* Why do you need it then? I mean that's the entire point

Comment: If you don't need dynamic polymorphism, then hould you inherit? Perhaps composition is better.

Comment: If you do not need it, don't do it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292124/is-there-any-reason-not-to-make-a-member-function-virtual.

Comment: You will just suffer an overhead of vtable and virtual calls without gaining any benefits from them... @MatthieuBrucher You make it sound like inheritance should be used only with dynamic polymorphism...

Comment: @VTT only said "perhaps", too many people inherit when they should actually compose.

Comment: You probably want to enforce no dynamic declaration in that case. Why inherit and then hide the base function? Why not just have two different, unrelated, classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A library/program should only support things that are meaningful, and if you do not intend / you want to prohibit that a class `Derived` is a possible substitute for an object of type `Base`, then you should not offer this possibility at all.

With `class Derived : public Base`, you offer polymorphism, and if you offer it, it should behave as one expects. Offering a member with the same name as in the base class but not overriding it is clearly something that is not expected, and you you should have good reasons and good documentation when doing so.

If you do not want to offer polymorphism, you could either inherit `private` or you could compose:

```
class B {
public:
    int foo() { return 0; };
};

class D1 : private B {
public:
    int foo() { return B::foo() + 1; };
};

class D2 {
public:
    int foo() { return b.foo() + 1; };
private:
    B b;
};

int main() {

    // B *b = new D1;  // Error cannot cast to private base class B

    // B *b = new D2;  // D2 is not a subclass of B

}
```